# Will a Windows 8 KMS key allow older operating systems to be activated?

Tags: licensing, activation, windows-8, kms

To put our Windows 8 KMS key onto our KMS server running Server 2008 R2, it appears that we first need to remove the existing Windows 7/Server 2008 key.

Is this the case? If so, do the new Windows 8/Server 2012 KMS Keys still allow older operating systems (Windows 7 and Server 2008) to be activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is necessary to install [KB2757817](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2757817) in order to activate a Server 2012 KMS key on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Second, you need to clarify whether you actually have a Server 2012 KMS key. You will not be able to install a Windows 8 KMS key on a server, period. However, server KMS keys typically can activate client operating systems.

For example:

- Server 2008 R2 KMS keys will activate Server 2008 R2, Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows Vista.
- Server 2012 KMS keys will activate Server 2012, Server 2008 R2, Server 2008, Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista.
- Windows 8 KMS keys cannot be installed on Windows Server operating systems, nor can they activate servers. They will activate Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista.

Comment: I'd installed the update, the 2012 keys seems to have gone on ok. Thanks